# How do I programmatically create JSON in XQuery in MarkLogic?

Tags: json, xquery, marklogic

I need to build up a JSON node in XQuery in MarkLogic. I know that I can use [`xdmp:unquote()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:unquote) to parse from a string into a `node()`. However, I’d like to build the JSON programmatically, without ugly string concatenation. I can use [computed element constructors](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery/langoverview#id_39188) to build XML nodes in XQuery. Is there something similar for JSON nodes?

Comment: Much more a MarkLogic question than a generic XQuery question. The way one did this in, say, BaseX would be different.

Comment: Yup. Thanks. I've updated the title and description to reflect this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JSON is implemented in MarkLogic as an extension to the XML data model. MarkLogic 8 introduces `object-node`, `array-node`, `number-node`, `boolean-node`, and `null-node` tests and constructors. Thus, in XQuery you can build JSON with computed constructors, just like you would with XML. For example,

```
object-node { 
  "key" || fn:string(xdmp:random(100)): array-node { 1, 2, 3 }, 
  "another": object-node { "child":  text {'asdf'} },
  "lastButNotLeast": boolean-node { fn:true() }
}
```

will create the JSON,

```
{
  "key47": [1, 2, 3],
  "another": {
    "child": "asdf"
  },
  "lastButNotLeast": true
}
```

Aside: In JavaScript you can build JSON-like structures as JavaScript objects using JavaScript syntax. You can convert a JavaScript object into a JSON node using [`xdmp.toJSON()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.toJSON). Most builtin functions that require a JSON node, however, will do this conversion automatically, such as [`xdmp.documentInsert()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.documentInsert).